# Resizing flash images on disk without affecting flash stage

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I've got an animation in Flash that's made of a number of large images - too large it turns out - flash keeps crashing and running out of memory.

I'd like to scale these down to 50% but maintain their on-stage size in Flash (or at least keep the positioned the same). I've scaled them down on disk, but this scales them in flash too (so messes up their relationships).

Does anyone know of a solution to this?

Comment: This is less of a programming question, you should try asking on superuser.com If you need to reposition the images, you could do it one go using the Edit Multiple Frames option, more here: http://www.biteycastle.com/lessons/emf.htm

Comment: Appologies - I did it without thinking really! I've posted it to superuser [here](http://superuser.com/questions/264785/resizing-flash-images-on-disk-without-affecting-flash-stage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the timeline your best bet is to wrap them into a MovieClip and scale that, or barring that select multiple frames and resize the smaller images in one go.

If using code to load the images, you could just scale all loaded images to a uniform size in the Loader complete event callback, regardless of their original dimensions.

Comment: I'm using the timeline. The thing is, at this point, the images are scaled fine, and I just want to scale their positions - not their sizes.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, what you can still do is to wrap them into a MovieClip and set the registration point to the centre (or however you need to position them), so regardless of the size they are going to be in the same place.